# How to get value of id of inner div in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On my page the `div` structure like this:

```php
<div class="row no-padding">
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-5 widget-left">
    <em class="glyphicon glyphicon-user glyphicon-l"></em>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-9 col-lg-7 widget-right">
    <?php echo '<div id="shop1" class="large">'. $row["0"]. '</div>';?>
    <div class="text-muted">User Details</div>
  </div> <!-- $row['id'] also in query for uniqueness -->
</div>
```

And look likes this:

[image]

While clicking on class `row no-padding` I want to alert text as “Hadapsar”, “Kolhapur” etc. Currently my jQuery code works only for class `large`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.large').click(function(event) {
    var ar = $(this).text();
    alert(ar);
    pune_shop(ar);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Please try this**.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.row.no-padding').click(function(event) {
        var ar = $(this).find('.large').text();
        alert(ar);
        pune_shop(ar);
    });
});
```